# How to configure artifactory CEPH S3 with Direct Upload Mechanism?

Tags: artifactory, ceph

Artifactory: 7.38.8
It works fine with the Eventual Upload Mechanism. I try to change it to the Direct Upload Mechanism, but I cannot upload any file.

My binarystore.xml configuration:

```
<config version="1">
    <chain>
        <provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">
            <provider id="s3" type="s3"/>
        </provider>
    </chain>
    <provider type="s3" id="s3">
        <bucketName>xxx</bucketName>
        <endpoint>xxx.xx.xx.xxx</endpoint>
        <port>8060</port>
        <credential>xxxxx</credential>
        <identity>xxxxx</identity>
        <s3AwsVersion>AWS2</s3AwsVersion>
        <httpsOnly>false</httpsOnly>
        <property name="s3service.disable-dns-buckets" value="true"/>
    </provider>
</config>
```

Error messages:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Expecting stream to be instance of FileWrappingInputStream"
  } ]

2022-08-16T07:56:25.351Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [31d9214b03152aae] [o.a.w.s.RepoFilter:315        ] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Upload request of example-repo-local:test/1/delivery/test.sh failed due to {}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Expecting stream to be instance of FileWrappingInputStream
```

Answer (score 1):

The chain defined in the storage configuration doesn't have an actual definition. Removing `<provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">` from the configuration file (binarystore.xml) and restarting Artifactory should help resolving the error.

[OR]

Amendment of cache settings for the definition you have made under  should help.

[image]